# Is SSRS Required to use Report Builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

Do I need SQL Server Reporting Services configured to create reports against SharePoint 2010 Lists using Report Builder 3.0 ?  I see that I can download an individual installer.

Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Reporting Services comes with two flavors - Native and SharePoint Integrated. This means if you want to create reports and display them on the browser , you can use the native mode and you can create reports using the business intelligence development studio.

You can leverage Performance Point Services and SharePoint Integrated SSRS mode for making reports out of sharepoint lists. Under this scenario, a report builder would be made available to you by SharePoint itself through the option of "edit with report builder" for any reports.

Basically you can create reports from any of the report builders (MSBI studio or Report Builder 3.0) for working with SharePoint integrated SSRS. So the answer to your question is "yes" you will need SQL Server Reporting Services configured to create reports against SharePoint 2010 Lists using Report Builder 3.0